# REGEX - Use Replace all occurrences of character between words/characters combination

Tags: regex

I have a CSV file that have a quoted field with the field terminator inside of it...

This is an example...

```
1|2|"hello everyone | I am Luis | I need to fix this"|3|123132
```

So basically I need a regular expression that will find the text between |" and "| and replace the inside of that capture group all of the | found.

Any idea on how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: The expected result would be to detect both pipes between |" and "| so that I can replace those pipe character with another one.

Comment: What regex language or tool are you using?

Comment: C#. Also been using regex101.com to test some expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I was able to sort it out. This is the expression I ended up with and hope it might help someone in future:

```
@"(?<=\|\"")(.*?\|?.*?)(?=\""\|)"
```

Thank you